# how to grant execute permission without read permission?

Tags: linux, permissions

I want to grant execute permission for a script, but not read permission since I do not want user to read the content for the script. But it seems not working, I post what I am doing and seeking for advice,

sub-directory demo is owned by root user and root group,

Case 1, make execute+read permission, works

chmod 775 /home/yhd/demo/text

Then user yhd can execute text command without any issues

Case 2, make execute permission only, not working

chmod 771 /home/yhd/demo/text

Then user yhn cannot execute text command, and error message is permission denied

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem with scripts is that the script is not what is running, but the *interpreter* (`bash` in this case).

The *interpreter* needs to read the script.

Since *reading* the file is forbidden then it can't be executed inside the interpreter.

This is different from a program, because programs are loaded directly into memory.

One solution is to use a compiler that will generate a C program equivalent to the script, like [SHC](http://www.datsi.fi.upm.es/%7Efrosal/sources/shc.html), that you can download from [here](http://www.datsi.fi.upm.es/%7Efrosal/sources/) or from this [guide](http://www.linux-magazine.com/Online/Features/SHC-Shell-Compiler).

Comment: Thanks for all the help jcbermu, mark your reply as answered.

Comment: so file permissions don't just apply to human users, but other programs as well?

Answer (score 5):

> how to grant execute permission without read permission?

Nope, is not possible: the interpreter needs to read script. What **@jcbermu** means is this one: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/34202/can-a-script-be-executable-but-not-readable

Comment: Vote up nice reply. Thanks for all the help duDE, nice name. :)